# axios.all concurrent request GET or POST only

Tags: javascript, vue.js, post, get, axios

Going through the axios docs, I'm trying to figure out if the **axio.all** construct for making concurrent requests works when the request are not all get request i.e can it work with a mix of GET and POST requests.

Comment: yes. it does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try performing multiple requests with your Axios client and using [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait on the result of all your requests.

Here's an example using JavaScript:

```js
const promiseGet = axios.get('/user?ID=12345')
const promisePost = axios.post('/user', { some: data })

const [responseGet, responsePost] = await Promise.all(promiseGet, promisePost)
```

Note that you should handle the possible errors (it's **not** described in the example above!)